# time format and string format

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL server  to form file names to Ms Word documents. The format is like this
clientnumber_date_time_clientname.doc.

Problem is Ms Word doesn't accept 10:19:23 time format as file name. How to change it into 10-19-23 format?

In some cases clent name is something like this: the "Coca Cola" company. Apparently, Ws Word doesn't accept "(double quotation) mark as file name. I' ve tried to change it into '(single quotation) mark via 'replace' , but it didn't work out. How to change "xxx" into 'xxx'?

Thanks in advance

here is part of that code

```
convert(varchar,e.ExternalID)+'_'+left(convert(varchar,@Now,120),10) +'uved'+'_'+convert(varchar,a.OwnerName)+'.doc' as NameFile
```

Comment: place some code.it can be helpful to understand what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following code.

```
DECLARE @CName varchar(100)
DECLARE @CNumber varchar(10)
SET @CNumber ='1234'
SET @CName = '"Coca Cola"'
SELECT @CNumber + '_' 
                + REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120),':','-'),' ' ,'_') 
                + '_' 
                + REPLACE(@CName,'"','''') 
                + '.doc'
```

Run this query and you will get exactly the same filename what you are expecting.

Comment: It seems the best solution. Thanks

Comment: One more question, how can I write quotation mark(") not like in above code but in other way (maybe it has unicode number or something like that)?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail. Not getting your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE` as in:

```
SELECT REPLACE([column],'oldstring','newstring')
FROM [MyTable]
```